# How to model changing state in functional programming

Tags: list, scala, object, functional-programming, immutability

I am new to FP and new to Scala and I have a question on how to solve a problem efficiently in a functional way.

Let's say I have:

`case class Store(storedObjects: List[StoreObject])`
and

`case class StoreObject(name: String)`

and I want to store all the `StoreObjects` in the `Store`.

How can I add new StoreObjects to the `List` the `Store` `case class` owns when it's immutable?

To take a second example: Suppose I have a `case class` `Person` as shown here,

`case class Person(name: String)` 
and an object called `object PersonController`

which owns an immutable list of `Person`s and every time I create a new `Person` I want to add it to the list in `PersonController`.

Is there a way how to do this in fp or a pattern?

Or is switching to mutability the only efficient way to do stuff like this (which would be painful because of multithreading).

Thanks for your help
Exagon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the main idea you're missing right now is the possibility to **not** mutate at all but actually create a new object with the result of your addition/removal operation.

For adding... something along these lines for example:

`def add(sObject: StoreObject, store: Store) = store.copy(storedObjects = store.storedObjects :+ sObject)`

This will return a new `Store` holding the list.

Hope this makes sense and answer your doubts.

Comment: thanks for your help isnt this very unefficient if the list is very large? and how to perform this "pattern" on the PersonController Object i mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

> how can i add new StoreObjects to the List the Store Class owns

Define a regular class with field

```
var list = List()
```

or

```
val list = mutable.List()
```

You can change this field in both cases: in first case by reassigning the var and in second by mutating the underlying `mutable.List`.

I would prefer the first way - `var` with immutable list, because you can safely share it among threads. But you have to ensure that update operations on `list` are correctly synchronized.